# $\mu$ is signed measure, and $f$ is integrable w.r.t. the total variation |$\mu$|. Show that $f$ is integrable w.r.t. $\mu^+$, $\mu^-$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Consider $\mu$ is signed measure, and $f$ is a real value integrable function w.r.t. the total variation |$\mu$|. Show that $f$ is integrable w.r.t. $\mu^+$, $\mu^-$ and

$\int f d\mu=  \int f d\mu^+ - \int f d\mu^-$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$\int\left|f\right|d\left|\mu\right|=\int\left|f\right|d\mu^{+}+\int\left|f\right|d\mu^{-}$